# How to find an element in array which is a subelement in the Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
likes: {
        count:{type: Number, default: 0},
        authors:{type: [String], default: []}
    }
```

This is schema for the likes section. And I want to look if the given username is in the authors array or not ? How to create query for this situation?

`await Entry.findOne({ 'likes.authors': { $in: user.username },_id: entryId  }  )`

I have created a query like this but I couldn't get the data while I have a data which has `entryId` and contains `user.username` inside of `'likes.authors'`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Entry.findOne({'likes.authors': {$elemMatch: {type: user.username}},_id:entryId});
```